# Where to copy a readonly data file from bundle?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm a bit confused.  I'm including in the bundle a Core Data file that will not be modified by the user.  Apple rejected my app after I started copying the file to /Documents (due to the new iCloud requirements), so I now I copy the file over to /Library/myprivatedir/

The question is *why* do I need to copy over to /Library in the first place.  What's wrong with it staying in the Bundle after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with opening a CoreData store from within the bundle. Just be sure to pass the `NSReadOnlyPersistentStoreOption` as part of the options to `-addPersistentStoreWithType:configuration:URL:options:error:`

Comment: So there's no advantage of storing the file in other locations such as /Library/Private etc?

Answer (score 1):

Skimming the docs for [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) (apple id required) I found this

> ... Data that can be downloaded again or regenerated should be stored in the `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches` directory. Examples of files you should put in the Caches directory include database cache files and downloadable content, such as that used by magazine, newspaper, and map applications.

Because it is easily regenerated they may have taken issue with it.

A couple of points down may be useful if you did have a read/write database scenario

> ... Use the "do not back up" attribute for specifying files that should remain on device, even in low storage situations. Use this attribute with data that can be recreated but needs to persist even in low storage situations for proper functioning of your app or because customers expect it to be available during offline use. This attribute works on marked files regardless of what directory they are in, including the Documents directory. These files will not be purged and will not be included in the user's iCloud or iTunes backup. Because these files do use on-device storage space, your app is responsible for monitoring and purging these files periodically.

Comment: Yes, I know all about that after they rejected my app for storing in /Documents (as I originally stated).  My question is *WHY* move the data in the first place?  It's read-only data so it has no issues being in Bundle in the first place.